# Callback not working with ESP.deepsleep(time_interval_in_microseconds);

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I need help i am doing one project which uses Pubsubclient with ep8266 12-e and wifimanager . i have a callback function which is not receving anything once i use deep sleep with pubsub client but it is working fine with normal delay function.

```
void callback(char* topic,byte* payload,unsigned int length){
led_2();
char buff[22];
Serial.print("Message arrived in topic: ");
Serial.println(topic);
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
buff[i]=(char)payload[i];
}


if(strcmp(topic, "ios/interval") == 0)
{
    String test = String(buff);
    Serial.println(test);
    Serial.println("ok i am working");
    }
}
```

and in my void loop() function i am publishing data which is working fine and then i am doing deepsleep.But data in callback is not coming while performing the void loop operations and even after deep sleep.

Comment: you have to reset to get out of deepsleep, so i'm not sure a callback would work.

Comment: the esp starts new after deep sleep

Answer (score 1):

one more thing you have to connect REset to the D0 pin of nodeMCU only then this function will work. D0 is the hardware interrupt pin for NodeMCU, we have to wake the CPU up by pulling this pin to low. other than this you can also use void system_deep_sleep(uint32 time_in_us) function for deep sleep, These functions are ESP specific API for deep sleep

Comment: Yes, D0 to reset and then call this function ESP.deepSleep(interval, WAKE_RFCAL); and this interval is in microsecond not milli second, i.e for the delay of say 6 sec the interval would be 6000000. and if this works kindly accept this answer y clicking tick mark